# Incorrect bitwise result

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

I'm working on a C project for a PIC microcontroller in MikroC and have a function:

```
void Write_SPI_32(unsigned long Address, unsigned long Data);
```

That only sometimes works:

```
Write_SPI_32(0x300000 + 12, 0b10001111000010100000000000000000);     //Gives expected result
Write_SPI_32(0x300000 + 12, 0x8f0a0000);                             //Gives expected result
Write_SPI_32(0x300000 + 12, 2399797248);                             //Gives expected result
Write_SPI_32(0x300000 + 12, (2 << 30) | (120 << 21) | (160 << 12));  //Gives UNEXPECTED result
```

How am I managing to noob the bitwise math here?

Comment: What is your expected results?

Comment: I'd use `(2ul << 30) | (120ul << 21) | (160ul << 12)`. It's better to avoid bit manipulation of signed types, unless required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`2 << 30` overflows a 32-bit `int`, as the nominal result would be 2<sup>31</sup>, but the largest value representable in `int` would be 2<sup>31</sup>−1, so the behavior is not defined by the C standard.

A typical behavior from a compiler would be that this produces the result −2<sup>31</sup> (the same bit pattern as 2<sup>31</sup> but interpreted with two’s complement), then the other operands (`120 << 21` and so on) are ORed in. Then, when the argument is converted to a 64-bit `unsigned long` to pass to `Write_SPI_32`, this negative `int` becomes an `unsigned long` with its high 32 bits set.

You can use `(unsigned long) 2 << 30` or `2ul << 30`. When shifting, it is often useful to cast the left operand to the ultimate destination type, so that the shift is performed in that type instead of in the default type that results from the integer promotions.